# Scheduled jobs running but not successfully updating

Tags: joomla, scheduled-job

I have just updated to CiviCRM 5.4.1 and system status says the cron is running OK. However, the member statuses and the scheduled reminders are not being updated. These jobs were being run successfully in the summer but stopped at some point before I updated to the new version. Suggestions?

Comment: have you looked in the log for those jobs to check if it is telling you they are failing

Comment: Yes but they all say Success. The Scheduled Reminders job says - 2018-09-12 13:00:02 Send Scheduled Reminders 
Entity: Job Action: send_reminder
Summary
Finished execution of Send Scheduled Reminders with result: Success (1) and the Update Membership Statuses says - 2018-09-12 18:00:02 Update Membership Statuses 
Entity: Job Action: process_membership
Summary
Finished execution of Update Membership Statuses with result: Success (Processed 121 membership records. Updated 0 records.) However, statuses have not been updated per the Status Rules.